# Checking if a sqlite database is open or used somewhere

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a C++/ Sqlite utility to compare 2 databases and merge the tables which are there in 1st and not in 2nd. Now I want that if the database in which the new tables are to be added is open or used in some other process at that time the merging should not happen and a proper error should be displayed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the database file is accessed only through the SQLite library, you can use [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) to check whether somebody else has an active transaction.

However, open but inactive connections cannot be detected by this. You would have to use some mechanism of the operating system to check for open files.